# OSX Major Graphics Bug

Tags: graphics, error, imovie

[image]

I was trying to use iMovie but every time it eventually does this. I used to think this was May graphics overheating (because iMovie puts my temps around 180 when running) but I saw right before it happened it seemed to be auto saving. I can't tell if it is a hardware or software issue but I hope someone can figure it out. I know that it is graphics based because if I leave the computer idle for a minute the clock starts working but as soon as I move the mouse it freezes again. This issue appears other times when I am running my computer but mostly with iMovie.

Also, this is the first time it's happened: When I pressed the power button the options popup appeared, I dragged it along the screen and that seemed to clear out the bug. iMovie's rendering box is pink but I was able to get my computer's info after doing this to put in this post.

**Computer Info**

MacBook Pro 13-inch, Mid 2010

2.4 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo

*Upgraded* 16 GB 1067 MHz DDR3

NVIDIA GeForce 320M 256 MB

OS X 10.9.2

*Upgraded* 1 TB Hybrid Drive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for providing a picture. Unfortunately, based on the image, I can definitively tell you this is a hardware problem. Specifically, your GPU has failed.

If you wish to confirm this at home, you can do so by [taking a screen shot](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5775) the next time it occurs. If the distortion appears on your screenshot, then the problem is with your graphics processor and you to get your logic board replaced. If the distortion does not appear on the screenshot, then the issue is with your display and you need to get your display replaced. *Either way, it's a hardware issue for which no online troubleshooting or solution exists**

*As a makeshift solution to failing/failed GPUs, many users have resorted to using [gfxCardStatus](http://gfx.io) to force the discrete GPU off.

Best of luck.

Comment: Ok, I wouldn't say it has completely failed *yet* but it is a GPU issue because earlier today I did just that (take a screenshot). I am going to try one other thing and that is external PCI chassis. It is a long shot through USB but it would work until I get to building a computer this summer.

Comment: @b2550 Yes, most certainly GPU. Regardless of how you proceed from here, just make sure you have a current backup of your data. Best of luck.

Comment: @njboot My first thought would be that this is a RAM problem. The videocard uses a share of the installed RAM memory and I am most certain this could be caused by faulty (non Apple) RAM.